# How can i call a service and then have the service make a call to calling component without NullInjectorError

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a way to call from a component a function on service and then when its finished call from the service a function on the component that has made the call to the service.

In my situation i have a component that handles most of tmy grid function. As i am trying to clean up my code i created a service that handles the reading and writing of any data to my local app store. All that works fine as long as i don't have to access any function on my component that made the call to service.

I tried to just specify the calling component in the constructor which creates the error that we have a NullInjectorError

> core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(FarmsModule)[GridFiltersService -> GridFiltersService
> -> AgGridBaseComponent -> AgGridBaseComponent -> AgGridBaseComponent]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for AgGridBaseComponent!
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(FarmsModule)[GridFiltersService ->
> GridFiltersService -> AgGridBaseComponent -> AgGridBaseComponent ->
> AgGridBaseComponent]:

When i go and try to use the @ViewChild  iget another error

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AgGridBaseComponent' before
> initialization

So for now the only way i was able to work around this is to have the service return the data and then call the function in my componenet like this

```
this.onSearchFilterChanged(this.gridFilterService.doSomething(this.gridGuid))
```

Even so this works its not ideal and i hope there is another way to make this work.

here is wat i ultimately trying to do

on init I want to call my function in service

```
this.gridFilterService.doSomething(this.gridGuid)
```

then the service function looks like this agGridbase is the component that called the service and also holds the onSearchFilterChanged function

```
doSomething(gridGuid : string) {
        const gridFilters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridFilters'));
        if (gridFilters) {
            let activeFilters: any = gridFilters.find(x => x.gridGuid === gridGuid)
            if (!activeFilters) {
                activeFilters = {};
            }
            if (activeFilters && activeFilters.qstype && activeFilters.qsearch && activeFilters.qtypeText) {
                this.agGridBase.onSearchFilterChanged({
                    newValue: activeFilters.qsearch,
                    qstype: activeFilters.qstype,
                     qtypeText: activeFilters.qtypeText
                 });

            }
           
        }
    }
```

And this is the onSearchFilter changed Function in agGridBase

```
onSearchFilterChanged(filterResult: IAgGridSearchFilterResult) {
this.updateDataFetcherParam('qsearch', filterResult.newValue);
this.updateDataFetcherParam('qstype', filterResult.qstype);
this.updateDataFetcherParam('qtypeText', filterResult.qtypeText);

this.gridFilterService.updateFilter(filterResult, this.gridGuid)

this.onGridReload.emit(
    {currentDataFetcherParams: {qsearch: filterResult.newValue, qstype: filterResult.qstype, qtypeText: filterResult.qtypeText}}
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) in the service should do the trick for you.

in the service:

```
  finished$ = new Subject<YoutDataType>();
  ...

  doSomething() {
   ...    
   
   this.finished$.next(yourData) // this can be called anywhere in this service
  }
```

from your component:

```
onInit() {
  this.yourService.finished$.subscribe(yourData => {
     // in here you can do something else, after "doSomething()" finishes
  })


  this.yourService.doSomething()
}
```

Don't forget to avoid the [memory-leak](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject) trap with this subscription.

Comment: Thanks, i just updated the Question above with the more detailed code as the answer / subject might work but not in the way i need it to. Based on your answer i create a subject in the Service and then from the component subscribe to it.  But this does not solve how i can call a function on the component once i am finished and pass data to the function as well. The way i see your sample is almost like the **this.onSearchFilterChanged(this.gridFilterService.doSomething(this.gridGuid))** just that i call it async and wait for it to complete vs my sync call

Comment: if there are no async calls in `doSomething` the observable yields synchronously.  You could also call `this.yourService.finished$.next(yourData)` from the component (if that is what you intend)

Comment: So based on how i see this , your code does the same as me calling it like your subject except in your case we wait before its completed.  Which is still not allowing me to call the function from service but i have to call it from component and get the data from service.